# IIS on Windows 7 Ultimate: Remote Connections?

Tags: windows-7, iis

I have IIS freshly installed on Windows 7 Ultimate (in a virtual box). From the (guest) machine itself, I can connect using http://localhost or the IP address. I can ping this IP address from the host machine, but cannot connect via HTTP. Does IIS automatically allow remote connections? If not, how may I turn this on?

**Note:** Guest and host can ping each other using their respective IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to open the port in the firewall, under the Control Panel. Allow port 80 (www) incoming.